# Caching ASHX Image Response

Tags: c#, caching, image-processing, asp.net-4.0, ashx

I have created an ashx file to generate image thumbnails on the fly. I would like to cache these images client side after they are called the first time.

URL:

> ~/image.ashx?dir=user&w=25&h=25&force=yes&img=matt.jpg

Code Behind:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    TimeSpan refresh = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(refresh));
    context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(refresh);
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
    context.Response.CacheControl = HttpCacheability.Public.ToString();
    context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

    string dir = context.Request.QueryString["dir"];
    string img = context.Request.QueryString["img"];
    bool force = context.Request.QueryString["force"] == "yes";
    double w = 0;
    double h = 0;
    ...
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    thumb.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Using the Dev Tools in Chrome I can see the following Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2011 19:17:31 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=...; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 902
Connection: Close
```

Can someone enlighten me as to why this isn't caching on multiple calls with the same exact URL? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely this line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
```

Should be:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

Comment: @SubinJacob - These are cache headers. What are you talking about?

Comment: I want to make the cache expire if the content(image) changed by the user

Comment: @SubinJacob - Why not ask a new question then?