# Setting an Image control source to an image in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to show an image on my Image control but it isn't working. I'm using it as a screenshot preview basically. I have the bitmap save to the Images folder in the server path, and then I set the ImageUrl for the control to that saved image location. Here is the code I have. This code executes on a button click:

```
img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + "test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + "test.png";
Image1.DataBind();
```

No exceptions are caught, and the image is saving correctly in the path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Server.MapPath for URL's, change to this (presuming that images folder is in the root folder of your application):

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/images/test.png";
```

update:

As Graymatter suggested ih comments that should be :

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/test.png";
```

I overlooked that we are talking about Image server control

Comment: Ah, duh. I should've know that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You should never hard code the path like that. You can't guarantee where your site will be hosted on the box (root/virtual directory).

Comment: @Graymatter - Would "~/images/test.png" work instead? If not, what would you suggest in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to link to write directly to a web folder in an application. I would rather go the route of creating an ashx handler and stream back the image. You could create a file (e.g. getmyimage.ashx.cs) that looks something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class getmyimage : IHttpHandler 
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.WriteFile("x:\myimages\test.png");
        Response.End();
  }

  public bool IsReusable 
  {
    get 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

getmyimage.ashx would contain something like this:

```
<% @ webhandler language="C#" class="getmyimage" %>
```

In this code, "x:\myimages\test.png" would be the image you would like to stream back to the browser. You can add parameters to the getmyimage.ashx url to specify which image should be loaded. You can also modify the code to generate the image on the fly or something along those lines.

You could then point to the "getmyimage.ashx" in the image URL. So your imageurl would look like this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "getmyimage.ashx"
```

As Antonio indicated in the comments, you need to look at the type of caching options you want and set them. The default behavior is to always send back the image and not cache it. If you want to cache the image, you should look at the following post:

[Caching ASHX Image Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560180/caching-ashx-image-response)

To map directly to the image in the question, you can use this:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/test.png"
```

Comment: +1 for the last line ;) Just to mention that your should set cache options or browsers will ask for your image(s) every time user reloads a page or that same image is used on another page. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560180/caching-ashx-image-response

Comment: @AntonioBakula One thing that scares the living daylights out of me is writing to the web site folders. It's really risky which is why I dive on questions like this with other alternatives :)