# Prevent caching of Images on webpage

Tags: javascript, image, caching, azure, blob

I am using an IHttpHandler to display an image stored in an azure blob on a webpage. This works fine. I also give the user the ability to rotate the image. The code to rotate the image is working. However when I then try to show the rotated image to the user:

```
document.getElementById("imageControl").src = "/ImageHandler.ashx?container=images&ID=blobFileName;
```

the image shown on the page is not updated although the image stored at 'blobFileName' has been changed. After some trial and error I found that if I store the rotated blob under a new file name, say 'blobFileNameRotated' the code:

```
document.getElementById("imageControl").src = "/ImageHandler.ashx?container=images&ID=blobFileNameRotated;
```

works and displays the rotated file. I assume that the original code doesn't work because the image has been cached by the browser? I tried running the code in a couple of browsers and found that in Chrome the original code works, but only for small files, and that it doesn't work at all in IE11.

My question is how can I control how a browser caches the image file (if that is the problem) and force the browser to re-display the image even if I haven't changed the file name. I tried setting src to a different file and then back to the blob file but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an Azure issue but a few things to try:

1. You could add a cache-buster to your Image Handler URL.  I'd recommend just appending a random number on the end to force the browser to re-request the URL. The problem is no image will ever be cached.  Example:

   `document.getElementById("imageControl").src = "/ImageHandler.ashx?container=images&m=" + Date.now();`
2. Use the same approach but output the number of images to be shown and change Date.now() to am image name / ID so that we as you rotate you will eventually get the same image which should be cached.

   `// output using some server-side logic.`

   `var imageIds = new Array("ImageA","ImageB","ImageC");`

   `// in an eventHander have similar to:`

   `document.getElementById("imageControl").src = "/ImageHandler.ashx?container=images&ID=" + imageIds[currentImage]`
3. Make sure you set the correct cache headers in your hander's C# code.  See [Caching ASHX Image Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560180/caching-ashx-image-response)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the slow response to this, my solution was sort of working so I've only just got round to testing out Simon's better solutions. I thought I would add some other things I've found out along the way in case others come to this question looking for information about blobs and images.

My solution involved changing the name of the file each time I rotated it. This meant that I stored a new blob for each 90 degree rotation. This worked but Simon's solution just involves changing the call to the imagehandler so the blob filename doesn't need to change.

I initially ran into problems because I didn't set the content type of the blob after I had rotated it. When I then tried to use the image in a report, the code complained because it wasn't an image type.

Note that if you want to copy the content type from the blob you are rotating it is not available after you have executed:

```
    Dim blob As ICloudBlob = GetBlob(sContainer, blobFileName)
```

but only after the blob has been downloaded:

```
    blob.DownloadToByteArray(byteData, 0)
```

This tripped me up at another time as well because I assumed that a blob had been found because I didn't get an error on the `dim blob as` line of code when in fact it couldn't have been found because I'd passed in the wrong container name.

Happy blobbing.